# activity call throws error

Tags: android

I have the code below that is supposed to parse an XML document.

I'm getting an error stating that 'activity cannot be resolved'.

How can I get my program to recognize my activity?

Thanks!

```
package me.HelloAndroid;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;

public class EncounterGenerator {

String encounterText;
int testint;
private String xmlValue;
private int encounterID;
public EncounterStats stats;

public EncounterGenerator() {
    Resources res = activity.getResources();
    XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.encounters);

    xpp.next();

    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
    { ... }
```

Comment: yeah, it doesn't compile does it? you don't pass a reference to your activity and yet your still referencing it like you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it written, `activity` is an undefined local variable. How do you anticipate this working? Either your class needs to accept an Activity parameter and save it off, like so:

```
public EncounterGenerator(Activity activity) {
    Resources res = activity.getResources(); 
    ...
}
```

Or some other way if that isn't appropriate in your application.